# Angular get current date to filter http.get request

Tags: angular, date, httprequest

```
  getStuff(currentUserId: any){
    const today = ?
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    const token = currentUser.token;
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/odata/User('+currentUserId+')/Stuff$filter=Date ????',{headers: headers})}
```

In this function I get some Stuff from my Api and everything I get has a Date. I want to filter the http.get request for stuff thats date is today or in the future.

My Problem is how do I get todays Date and how do I filter the stuff I want?

The Date Format in my Database is like that for example "2017-12-21 00:00:00.000"

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date as you like,

Either doing :

```
"$filter=" + date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() ...etc
```

See here for more info : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Or using the javascript format functions :

```
date.toLocaleDateString();
```

And then converting it back to a date on the server side

Comment: It tells me that those functions dont exist

Comment: You need to create a Date using new Date(); or pass the parameter as a Date

Comment: thats not working... like I have my Date now "2017-12-28 00:00:00.000" but the filter doesnt work
'...$filter=Date eq ' +date


            there is exactly 1 record with that date but its not working..